# Please rename [stackoverflow] to [stack-overflow]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request

The tag [stackoverflow](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stackoverflow) should be renamed to [stack-overflow](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stack-overflow) better to reflect the site's official name.

It's a tiny tag with just three open Qs but I can't think of any reason not to use the site's proper name. The site referred to is clearly that at https://stackoverflow.com/:

[image: Stack Overflow]

Its Usage guide is:

> Questions about Stack Overflow should be asked at Meta Stack Overflow

Ref: [stack-exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stack-exchange)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[stackoverflow](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stackoverflow) has been merged into [stack-overflow](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stack-overflow)and synonymized.

Comment: No problem.  It's the official branding, so I don't think anyone can really argue with this one.