# Please rename [hackernews] to [hacker-news]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

The tag [hackernews](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hackernews) should be renamed to [hacker-news](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hacker-news) better to reflect the site's official name.

It's a minor tag with just eight questions but I can't think of any reason not to use the site's proper name. The network referred to is clearly that at https://news.ycombinator.com/:

[image: First example of Hacker News]

and

[image: Second example of Hacker News]

Ref: [Rename [deviant-art] to [deviantart]](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4196/rename-deviant-art-to-deviantart])

Ref: [Please rename [stackoverflow] to [stack-overflow]](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4384/please-rename-stackoverflow-to-stack-overflow)

Ref: [Please rename [research-gate] to [researchgate]](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4383/please-rename-research-gate-to-researchgate)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is done

```
updating post history, 9 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 8 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
removing/renaming old tag, 1 rows affected
tag remapping of [hacker-news] and [hackernews] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
1 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
0 tracked tag badges were remapped!
Tag Synonym hackernews -> hacker-news was approved!
```